# Where to add server logic using Swagger codegen with Lumen Server Stub

Tags: swagger, lumen, swagger-codegen

I have been looking around but haven't been able to find anything concrete on this so apologies if it has been asked before.

I am using [Swagger codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to create a ServerStub for my [Lumen API project](https://lumen.laravel.com/) that I am making which is working just fine. My confusion comes from where am I meant to put in my server side logic for connecting to the database, etc.

All files in the `middleware` and `controllers` folders, as well as `routers.php` explicitly state **Do not edit the class manually** in the header comments of each class. So I'm a bit confused where I am supposed to put my logic after the creation of the Server Stub.

Can anybody shed light on where to I put my implementation of the project to use the Server Stub provided? Because the comments tells me not to edit the class, I feel like my implementation is meant to be abstracted away somewhere but I'm just not sure where.

Appreciate any help on the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you to start a discussion in github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/ if you've not done so.

Comment: @XanT I'm using Slim, and I'm having very similar problem. I get the server stub, and I have some implementation for it. How do I connect between the two without changing the stub files (to be able to regenerate them in the future when the API evolves). Did you find any solution for it?

It sounds such a fundamental issue, and I can't understand how it is not written in any good tutorial.

Comment: @nheimann1 I am afraid not. I ended up just manually creating my controllers and so forth and have annotated my code with [swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) so now I can convert it to the swagger spec. Wasn't exactly the solution I wanted but was what I ended up going with in the end.

Comment: @nheimann1  Were you able to figure this out?  I've been searching for this also and have not been able to find an answer.